# Regarding a handle for SOAP response string

Tags: c, soap, libcurl

I am trying to send a SOAP request to a webservice and receive the response back using C. I was directed to an example of "simplepost.c" and using that, I am able to send and print a SOAP response back from a web service on my command line. But instead of printing the response on the screen, I want a handle to the response string, so that I am able to extract the values inside the SOAP tags. I have the following send and receive program written, but i am not able to receive proper response, which means either there is problem in sending or receiving. If any one can help me locate how exactly can I achieve, what i want, it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

/* Auxiliary function that waits on the socket. */ 

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  /* Minimalistic http request */ 
  const char *request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <S:Envelope xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"xmlns:tns=\"http://ThermodynamicProperties/\"><S:Body> <tns:getSpeciesInformation> <speciesSymbol>CO2</speciesSymbol> <phase>GAS</phase> </tns:getSpeciesInformation> </S:Body> </S:Envelope>";

size_t iolen;

  struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://thermo.sdsu.edu/servlet/ThermodynamicProperties/ThermodynamicPropertiesService");

    /* Do not do the transfer - only connect to host */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECT_ONLY, 1L);


    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(CURLE_OK != res)
    {
      printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(res));
      return 1;
    }

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, request);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);

    puts("Sending request.");
    /* Send the request. Real applications should check the iolen
     * to see if all the request has been sent */ 
    res = curl_easy_send(curl,request, strlen(request), &iolen);

    if(CURLE_OK != res)
    {
      printf("Error: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
      return 1;
    }
    puts("Reading response.");

    /* read the response */ 

printf("ok1 \n");
      char buf[10240];
  res = curl_easy_recv(curl, buf, 10240, &iolen);
 printf("ok2 \n");
      if(CURLE_OK != res)

     {
printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(res));

       }
else{  printf("data %s \n", buf);


    }

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The response I am getting is:
Sending request.
Reading response.
ok1 
ok2 
Error: .lib section in a.out corrupted

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html), because it deals with all the send/receive part and also parses and constructs the soap messages.

If you want to work with curl and manual parsing for sure you have a wrong contanty type. It has to be

```
Content-Type:text/xml
```

in SOAP 1.1 or

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;
```

in SOAP 1.2 and I've seen that without the correct content type many web services don't even respond.

But really consider using a tool to generate the stubs and just focus on the logic of the program. Writing a parse by hand is in general bad.